# Why is my SSL not working on mobile for WWW?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, mobile

I have a Lets Encrypt SSL cert on my website. 
I have the site redirecting from non-Https to Https.

My issue is WWW is not redirecting on mobile.

**example**: https://www.mysite should redirect to https://mysite

I'm getting a "connecting is not private!" error.

I tried adding a rewrite rule in htaccess with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure that you are using HTTPS in WordPress settings Please following the below URL: 
https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-common-ssl-issues-in-wordpress-beginners-guide/

Comment: Okay Please check you htaccess rules & wp-config.php file related to set ssl